# update span tag value with javascript issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simply update a span tag usign the following method...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML="newtext";  

</script>

<span id="myspan"> hereismytext </span>
```

But i am getting the following error:

**document.getElementById("myspan") is null**

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you need to add that javascript after the element (the element has to be first created in DOM for the javascript to see it):

```
<span id="myspan"> hereismytext </span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML="newtext";  
</script>
```

Or use `window.onload`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML="newtext";  
    }
</script>
<span id="myspan"> hereismytext </span>
```

Comment: It's not because you need to put the Javascript after the element. You need the javascript to run after the element is known to the browser, which is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your JavaScript code into a function, and calling it in the page onload handler - as things stand, if you have your script tag at the top of the page then the DOM (and therefore your span) won't exist at the time your code gets executed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
funcion loaded(){
    document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML="newtext";  
}
</script>

<body onload="loaded()">
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're communicating with the DOM, you need to make sure that it exists/is ready to be modified. In your example, you're changing an element with the id `myspan` before it exists (the javascript is running before the html) and therefore the browser cannot find it. You either need to put it after:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//change html
</script>
```

Or check wait until it's ready.

```
window.onload = function() {
    //change html
}
```